# What is the failure rate of orthodontic treatments?

Tags: oral-health, gums, retainers, dental-braces

For orthodontic treatments such as braces, after completion of treatment, sometimes teeth return to their original position or some degree of misalignment.  How frequently does this occur?  How often does it occur if maintenance (such as retainers) treatments are done properly?

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). We'd love to help, but the way it is written the question both asks for personal medical advice and has several questions in one, which makes it very difficult to answer. We can't write about personal experiences (e.g. if anyone has experienced something) but we can offer science-based answers (e.g. what is the statistics on teeth returning to their original position). Or, are there any general hygiene advice for people with braces. May I suggest [edit]ing your question to make it more on-topic. You can have a look at our [help] for guidance. Thanks!